# Android studio conection with SQL table DB browser

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, connect

Straight to point:

I am making a Quizz app in Android studio. I would like to get the question (and answers) that will fill the app from SQL table that i made in DB browser for SQLite.

My question is how do i connect those two (without rettyping all those question in android studio).

I have in somethin like a structure {ID, qusetion, answer} and I only point ID number i whant to fetch from the table and it fills my array in android studio.

I hope this make sense :)

Regards

Comment: I'd recommend reading the Android documentation regarding [saving and retrieving data from an SQLite database](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) first. As a quick note, Stack Overflow is designed to help with specific programming issues rather than broader situations like this, so also take a look at ["What topics can I ask here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What makes a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Alternatively, if you have created your structure and data in DB Browser, you could potentially export it as a raw .sql file, put it in /res/raw and then run that .sql file in your Database Handler's `onCreate` method.

Answer (score 0):

You could put every question and answer in a file, line by line, things separated by a specific character.

ex:

```
What's the color of the sky?;Blue;Red;Yello;Black
Who is Harry potter?;A magician;A girl;A burrito;A car
```

And read the file, and insert everything them in the database on the first time you open the app.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're able to export from DB Browser to a .sql file (including `CREATE TABLE` statements as you'll effectively be creating a new database from scratch), you can use this exported file to recreate your database in your app.

By overriding the [`SQLiteOpenHelper.onCreate()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onCreate(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase)) method, you could do something like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // Open the raw SQL file
    InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.mydb);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

    // Read the file
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      sb.append(line);
    }
    reader.close();

    // Pump the statements into the database
    String queries = sb.toString()
    for (String query : queries.split(";")) {
        db.execSQL(query);
    }
}
```

Replacing `mydb` with whatever the name of your sql file is in `/res/raw`

Comment: IOUtils is not a class from android, if you mentioned it , you should had also put a compile link or something.

Comment: Very true, that's what I get for lifting straight from another question :) Will update with a more appropriate solution for file reading.